# JDBC resultset not working when using aliases I receive " java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted to execute this query, but it gave me an error without using variables but it gave me an error ORA-00905: missing keyword.
I tested the query in SQL Developer and it ran with no errors. I'm probably think it's a driver issue or a syntax issue with JDBC. But I have no idea here's the code:

```
    public List<ReimbBean> getAllReimb() {

    String sql = "select reim.reimb_id, reim.reimb_amount,"
            + "reim.reimb_submitted, reim.reimb_resolved, "
            + "CONCAT(CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' '),"
            + " u.user_last_name) AS \"REIMB_AUTHOR\", "
            + "reim.REIMB_RESCRIPTION, rst.REIMB_STATUS, "
            + "rtype.REIMB_TYPE, CONCAT(CONCAT(urs.user_first_name,'   '), "
            + "urs.user_last_name) AS \"REIMB_RESOLVER\""
            + "FROM ERS_REIMBURSTMENT reim"
            + "LEFT JOIN ERS_USERS u"
            + "ON u.ERS_USERS_ID = reim.REIMB_AUTHOR"
            + "LEFT JOIN ERS_REIMBURSTMENT_STATUS rst"
            + "ON rst.REIMB_STATUS_ID = reim.REIMB_STATUS_ID"
            + "LEFT JOIN ERS_REIMBURSTMENT_TYPE rtype"
            + "ON rtype.reimb_type_id = reim.REIMB_TYPE_ID"
            + "LEFT JOIN ERS_USERS urs"
            + "ON urs.ERS_USERS_ID = reim.REIMB_RESOLVER"
            + "ORDER BY reim.reimb_id";
  List<ReimbBean> reimbAllList = new ArrayList<>();  
  ReimbBean reimb = new ReimbBean();

  try {
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement =    conn6.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); 

        while(rs.next()){

            reimb.setReimbAmount(rs.getDouble("reimb_Amount"));
            reimb.setReimbDescript(rs.getString("reimb_Description"));
            reimb.setReimbSubmitted(rs.getTimestamp("reimb_Submitted"));
            reimb.setReimbAuthor(rs.getInt("reimb_Author"));
            reimb.setReimbResolved(rs.getTimestamp("reimb_Resolved"));
            reimb.setReimbResolver(rs.getInt("reimb_Resolver"));
            reimb.setReimbStatusID(rs.getInt("reimb_Status_ID"));
            reimb.setReimbTypeID(rs.getInt("reimb_Type_ID"));

            reimbAllList.add(reimb);
        }
```

I read online that the preapareStatement is unable to bind objects only variables, so the alternative was to define them explicitly, so I created a part for declarations and substituted the fields with String variables, but the error continues to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing whitespaces at the end of a lot of those strings:

```
String sql = "select reim.reimb_id, reim.reimb_amount,"
           + "reim.reimb_submitted, reim.reimb_resolved, "
           + "CONCAT(CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' '),"
           + " u.user_last_name) AS \"REIMB_AUTHOR\", "
           + "reim.REIMB_RESCRIPTION, rst.REIMB_STATUS, "
           + "rtype.REIMB_TYPE, CONCAT(CONCAT(urs.user_first_name,'   '), "
           + "urs.user_last_name) AS \"REIMB_RESOLVER\" " // Here
           + "FROM ERS_REIMBURSTMENT reim " // and here
           + "LEFT JOIN ERS_USERS u " // and here
           + "ON u.ERS_USERS_ID = reim.REIMB_AUTHOR " // and here
           + "LEFT JOIN ERS_REIMBURSTMENT_STATUS rst " // and here
           + "ON rst.REIMB_STATUS_ID = reim.REIMB_STATUS_ID " // and here
           + "LEFT JOIN ERS_REIMBURSTMENT_TYPE rtype " // and here
           + "ON rtype.reimb_type_id = reim.REIMB_TYPE_ID " // and here
           + "LEFT JOIN ERS_USERS urs " // and here
           + "ON urs.ERS_USERS_ID = reim.REIMB_RESOLVER " // and here
           + "ORDER BY reim.reimb_id";
```

Comment: That definitely worked, but now I have this error "java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation", I'm assuming due to the fact that since I used a join statement to get a user's full name in the CONCAT() function which is a string but I am using a resultSet to return their id, which is an int. How would I get around this?

Comment: The line which contains "reimb.setReimbAuthor(rs.getInt("reimb_Author"));"

Comment: Here's a list of the tables and their corresponding fields:

Comment: @user3116769 `reimb_Author` is clearly a string (as you produce it with `concat`, like you noted). You should use `rs.getString` to retrieve its value, not `rs.getInt`.

Comment: `ERS_Reimburstment_Type(
    Reimb_Type_ID     NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Reimb_Type        VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Reimb_Type_PK PRIMARY KEY  (Reimb_Type_ID)`

Comment: Oh okay, but it is referenced by its foreign key, so I used the CONCAT() to get it's subfield, remb_author is just suppose to be an number. the hierachy is suppose to be  "users(id, username, password, lastname) --> reimb_author(users.id, users.username,....)"

Comment: @user3116769 `reimb_Author` is `CONCAT(CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' '),  u.user_last_name)` in your select-clause, so clearly it is not going to be a number.

Comment: I understand, so at this point I'm assigning the CONCAT(CONCAT(u.user_first_name...)) to the variable "Reimb_Author", which will make it a string at that point instead of maintaining it's original value as an integer.

Comment: @user3116769 yup, indeed.